# R RODBC - sqlSave decimal precision issues

Tags: rodbc

I'm using sqlSave from R to Oracle using RODBC. I'm saving numbers with decimal places and getting extra decimal places. For example:

195.45 from R shows up as

192.45000000000002 in Oracle

Comment: Looks like your number is being treated as floating point somewhere in the process.You need a decimal (fixed point) type